# Turn off the number of people like my site, in Like Facebook button

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I have a Like button in my web site connected to Facebook and works fine. But can I remove the number of people like my site and make it visible only if this number is bigger that 50?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could query the number and only make the displayed part of your site visible if the query returns higher than 50, otherwise just display some filler content (or a bigger "Like" button).

Comment: You mean do this:$query = "SELECT  like_count, from link_stat where  url='http://www.blabla.com/'";
    
        $data = array(
            'method' => 'fql.query', 
            'query' => $query,
            'callback'  => ''
        );
             
        $fqlResult = $facebook->api($data);
        print_r ($fqlResult);

Comment: Do I need to create a Facebook application for this? Do I need the app id and key?

Comment: From your original post it was unclear as to which way you were accessing their "like" button.  I imagine from your previous comment that you're just using their widget implementation.  It seems like what you want you can't get from just the widget and you will need some sort of query ability.  This will most likely require you to go through their API.

Comment: Ok I can change the way I am doing it and not use the widget. Could you explain me how to do it?

Comment: There are two ways to access Facebook, their API or Facebook Query Language (FQL).  Both seem to have similar functionality.  From what i can read it looks like using FQL might be your best bet.  You could run a query on how many users "like" your page (though from my cursory reading it looks like they don't offer those statistics on non-Facebook pages) and conditionally display their like button or your own "like" button (without numbers but similar functionality).  The most up to date info on their page-fan table can be found here http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Page_fan_(FQL).